# Unable to align elements in mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have used a template to edit as per requirements but few elements are not aligned properly in mobile view.

I have tried to edit the Css file using `@media` and screen only syntax providing the resolution but no luck. It showed no effect on the page

```
<div class="categories">
  <ul class="cat">
    <li>
      <ol class="type">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".residential">Living room</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".office">Bedroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".commercial">Modular Kitchen</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.categories {
padding-bottom: 40px;
text-align: center;
}
ul.cat li {
display: inline-block;
}
ol.type li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
ol.type li a {
 color: #a7c44c;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 15px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border: 2px solid #a7c44c;
 border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;

}
ol.type li a.active {
background: #a7c44c;
color: #fff;
}
ol.type li a:hover {
background: #a7c44c;
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 changes might give you a better result: `ol.type li {  margin: 15px 0; }` & 
`.type, .cat{padding:inherit;}`

working **snippet**:

```css
.categories {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.cat li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ol.type li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

ol.type li a {
  color: #a7c44c;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 2px solid #a7c44c;
  border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

ol.type li a.active {
  background: #a7c44c;
  color: #fff;
}

ol.type li a:hover {
  background: #a7c44c;
  color: #fff;
}

.type,
.cat {
  padding: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="categories">
  <ul class="cat">
    <li>
      <ol class="type">
        <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".residential">Living room</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".office">Bedroom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".commercial">Modular Kitchen</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Woahhh...! Thanks alot Akber Iqbal...was struggling alot to sort these elements..Its working now. Thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome Mustafa, do accept the answer if it works for you :)